# Asserting values after a batch is executed in a test class

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to use System.assert in my test class.  I am trying to assert values of a record's field after my batch has been executed, as follows:

```
// Test class
test.startTest();
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new CostToBuild(), 50);
test.stopTest();

System.assertEquals((product_a.ECS__Product_Cost__c + product_b.ECS__Product_Cost__c), master_product_A.CTB_Product_Cost__c);
```

The batch is responsible for handling the arithmetic to make the assertion true. When the batch is executed, debug statements in the batch report that the object in the scope, i.e. master_product_A, has a CTB_Product_Cost__c value of 3.00 . When the system.assert function is ran, an error is thrown:

> > FATAL_ERROR System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 3.00, Actual: null

I am thinking this is due to the

```
// end of batch execute method
update scope; // List<sObject>
```

statement within the batch not executing properly in the test scenario.  Is this a common error? Can records not be updated from a batch within a testMethod?  If not, any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be helpful.  More code can be provided per request.

TL;DR Can the value of a field be updated from a batch executed within a test method, then asserted?  If so, how do you approach that?

Comment: To see the result of the `update`, you will need to re-query the object to get the changed value of `CTB_Product_Cost__c` in your test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The updates that the batch is making to the object won't be reflected in the calling test context code.

After the batch has completed (I.e. after `test.stopTest();`) you should perform a SOQL query to get the record or records you want to make the assertions on.

Answer (score 0):

use this to query:

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new CostToBuild(), 50);
test.stopTest();
AsyncApexJob aaj = [SELECT Id, Status, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, NumberOfErrors FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ID =: batchprocessid ];
```

and validate in asserts.